# Angular 2 set data from REST API using patchValue

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form and a few functions that look like below.

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.buildForm();
        this.loadData();
        this.success = false;
    }

    loadData(): void {
        this.countryService.getCountries().subscribe(list => {
            this.countries = new Select2Mapper('countryCode', 'name').getData(list);
            this.setDefaultCountry();
        });
    }

    setDefaultCountry(): void {
        console.log('Setting default country');
        console.log(this.accountCreateForm.get('company').value);
        this.accountCreateForm.get('company').patchValue({
            countryCode: "US"
        });
    }

    buildForm(): void {

        this.accountCreateForm = this.fb.group({
            company: this.fb.group({
                companyName: ['', [WPValidator.companyName]],
                countryCode: ['', [Validators.required]]
            }),
            administrative: this.fb.group({
                firstName: ['', [WPValidator.nameMandatory]]
            })
        });

        console.log('Form built');

        this.accountCreateForm.valueChanges
            .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

        this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now

    }
```

In the above example, I can see setDefaultCountry setDefaultTimeZone getting called after buildForm. I can't understand why the new values are reflecting in the UI. All I see in the UI is the complete list of values. Its not showing the patch value. Do I need to trigger any events before or after setting default value ?

Also, when I print the form value after setting default i.e., patchValue, I can see the updated value.

If it matters, I'm using an angular wrapper on select2 jquery plugin for country drop down

Comment: I tried to call ChangeDetectorRef after patch. That did not work as well.

Comment: No luck with NgZone too :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to import changeDetectionRef and call detectChanges().

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
```

Then inside your class,

```
constructor(private _cdr : ChangeDetectorRef){

}
```

later call `_cdr.detectChanges()` after `patchValue()`

Comment: As I mentioned in comments of question, I tried this earlier and it did not work

Comment: @TechCrunch try ``applicationRef.tick()``

Comment: That did not work as well. If it helps, I'm using a Select2 wrapper as in this - https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2/issues/76.